# store user profle picture after updating in android

Tags: android

I want to get user image and store the image so that when the user open the app again it find its user profile picture. i can select image but can not view it again after destroying the app and open it again

```
//this how i pick the image
final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Detailed.this, image);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detailed, popup.getMenu());
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        int id = item.getItemId();

                        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                           // Toast.makeText(Detailed.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                        }
                        //Toast.makeText(Detailed.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                        //Toast.makeText(Detailed.this,"working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                popup.show();//showing popup menu
            }
            });


//the function to pick and store image how can i retrieve it onresume
@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
           Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
           String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

           Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                   filePathColumn, null, null, null);
           cursor.moveToFirst();

           int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
           String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
           cursor.close();


           SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Detailed.this.getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.SHARED_PREF_NAME,
                   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
           editor.putBoolean(AppConfig.IMAGE_SHARED_PREF, true);
          editor.putString(AppConfig.IMAGE_SHARED_PREF1, selectedImage.toString());
           editor.putString(AppConfig.filepath, filePathColumn.toString());
           editor.commit();

           ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
           imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
//http://tjkannan.blogspot.co.ke/2012/01/load-image-from-camera-or-gallery.html
       }


   }
```

Comment: You have to store it on the server side because if you save it on local devices in a folder, SharedPref or anything related to the device all the stuff has gone destroy after uninstalling app.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem line -

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

The problem is that your are setting your Image in **onActivityResult** which is called only when you have selected an image from phone gallery or taken image from camera.

1.
Save the Selected path of image in SharedPreferences once you select an image in **onActivityResult** -

```
   editor.putString("picturepath", filePathColumn.toString());
   editor.commit();
```

2.
Place this code somehwere in **onCreate** so that is called every time you come back to your app -

```
String pathOfImage = sharedPreferences.getString("picturepath", null);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);

    if(pathOfImage.length()!=0){
     imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathOfImage));
     }
```